# Constant/coefficient order and naming in regression functions

Tags: regression, notation, function

This question relates to best practices in Maths and Statistics.

When looking at linear regression formulas, they are generally written as

$y = a + bx.$

However, in general algebra, the function for a straight line is generally written as

$y = mx + c$

and, incidentally, a quadratic is written as $y = ax^2 + bx + c.$

Can anyone explain why algebra typically lists the function elements in decreasing order of power ($x^3, x^2, x^1, x^0$) whereas statistics (regression) chooses otherwise.

Also, how come the algebraic notation for a straight line generally uses $m$ and $c$ in its notation, rather than $a$ and $b$.

Lastly: What would be considered "best practice" for the notation of regression functions (linear as well as exponential, polynomial and other non-linear functions), with regards to order, e.g. $ax + b$ vs $a + bx$, and naming/lettering of constants.

Is it just convention, or is it a practice that can be explained historically?

Comment: The convention that variable symbols often come from the end of the alphabet and constant symbols from the beginning goes back at least to Descartes. That doesn't explain $m$ for gradient, which is indeed what I remember from secondary (high) school in Britain. For polynomials, naming the highest power first in algebra is a convention, perhaps arising because the highest power is the biggest deal most often (for $|x| \gg 1$ especially). .

Comment: In statistics, I think the order is most obviously explained by trying a sequence of models with simplest version first, e.g. try linear $a + bx$; if you need it, add a quadratic term, $a + bx + cx^2$, etc. Once you have lots of coefficients, it is easiest to rewrite $a =: b_0, b =: b_1,$ etc. or $a =: b_1, b =: b_2,$ etc. and that fits better with vector or matrix notation.

Comment: $c$ is often just explained as "constant", which won't work in all languages. A good point to mention $\int 1/\text{cabin}\ d\text{cabin}$ as $\log \text{cabin} + c$ or "houseboat". The pun on $c$ and "sea" only works in English, I imagine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_joke